# unable to send scope variable data to the checkbox in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to set the checkbox true or false dynamically , but while passing the data from controller to ng-model the checkbox status is not changing.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model={{applicable_status}}>
 <label>Applicable</label>
 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.applicable_status = "true";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-init` directive to initialize application data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model=applicable_status>
 <label>Applicable</label>
   <pre ng-bind="applicable_status | json"></pre>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.init = function(){
       $scope.applicable_status = true;
   };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ng-init` in your code.

You just need to remove those **double quotes from "true"** just assign normal true value to your variable, and it will work perfectly

Change your code from:

```
$scope.applicable_status = "true";
```

To

```
$scope.applicable_status = true;
```

It will work fine!

[Check this JsBin](https://jsbin.com/jivupibube/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: he needs to remove the brackets as well ´ng-model={{applicable_status}}´ has to be ´ng-model="applicable_status"´